# How many DB queries ran per request when using cookie authentication?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, cookies, passport.js

i was reading about `cookie authentication` and how it works,
You store the `sessionID` inside a `cookie header` which will be available in every request to the server, the server then extract the `sessionID` and make a db query to the `Session DB` (in case mongo store is used) where it stores `sessionID` `user ID` as key and value, then you take the `User ID` and make another db query on `users table` to extract users info.

So is that true for every request we make 2 queries, isn't that inefficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is that true for every request we make 2 queries, isn't that
>   inefficient?

Yes, There will be 2 queries to the database.

But, it might not be considerably inefficient. (unless you are creating next Google ;))

1. Note that collections or tables that saves the `sessionID`s are indexed on that field in practice. That makes the search much faster. Same goes for the user's collection or table as well. Getting user's information from `userid`
2. You can use [in-memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database) database to save the `sessionID`s. You might want to look at [Redis](https://redis.io/) ([express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) page states that [radis-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis) has more than 2k stars.)